# How to calculate the weighted average price on binance?

Tags: blockchain, ether, binance, price, trading

can somebody please answer the question below?

What is the weighted average trade price of the ETH/USDT SPOT trading pair on the Binance.com platform on January 1st, 2023, in UTC time, considering the ETH amounts in each trade? The sum of the first 8 digits after the decimal point of the result should be 37.